# bisectDate only returns largest or smallest i

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I completed followed this example http://arnauddri.github.io/d3-stock/
but used my own data.

```
Date,Close,Volume,Adjclose
9/21/16,10.17,5108600,10.17
9/20/16,10.76,7645400,10.76
9/19/16,11.09,17056700,11.09
9/16/16,12.29,12305200,12.29
9/15/16,10.62,3752400,10.62
```

whenever I hover over the line it shows "uncaught type error, date undefined. 
While debugging I found that not matter where I hovered on the line, the index only shows 1 or the largest. I think that's the problem. 
Can someone help? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the same data format from the example:

```
Date,Volume,Close,Average
14/01/2010,108223500,28.33,27.88904762
15/01/2010,148516900,27.86,27.9647619
19/01/2010,182501900,29.09,28.09380952
```

where the Date should be DD/MM/YYYY, followed by the volume and prices.